# How to add really long hexadecimal registry in custom action in wix installer?

Tags: wix, registry, registrykey

I get an error when I try to use a custom action to add a really long registry value before uninstall.

```
<CustomAction Id="InsertValue" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Directory="INSTALLDIR" ExeCommand="&quot;reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\HotKeys&quot; /v 9530 /t REG_BINARY /d <REALLY LONG HEXADECIMAL VALUE>"/>
```

The value is deleted on install and I need to write it back during uninstall but the value is longer than 255 characters so it is giving me a string overflow error.

What other options do I have to write such long values into the registry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code. This is the correct way to write to registries from wix.

```
 <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
                 Key="SOFTWARE\Intel\Display\igfxcui\HotKeys">
        <RegistryValue Name="9530"
                       Action="write"
                       Value="LONG HEXADECIMAL VALUE"
                       Type="binary"
                       KeyPath="yes" />
      </RegistryKey>
```

You should write this between a component tag.